# Instantiating and returning an object

Tags: java, oop, object, instantiation

I am trying to instantiate and return my results as an object, but I am not sure how to do so. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Current Code

```
private static Results stats(int[] data) {
    int      sum = 0,
            range,
            count = 0,
            max = data[0],
            min = data[0],
            mode,
            middle = data.length / 2,
            cardinality = data.length;
    double   mean = 0,
            median;
    Stats Results = new Stats();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        sum += data[i];
        if (data[i] < min){
            min = data[i];
        }
        if (data[i] > max){
            max = data[i];
        }
        if (data[i] > count){
            count = data[i];
            mode = i;
        }
    }
    if (data.length % 2 == 1){
        median = data.length / 2;
    } else {
        median = data[middle - 1] + data[middle] / 2;
    }
    mean = sum / data.length;
    range = max - min;    
}
```

Edit Here is the class which is inside public class Stats

```
static class Results {
  public int[] data; 
  public int cardinality;
  public int range;
  public double mean;
  public double median;
  public int mode;
  public boolean nomode;
```

}

Here is all of the code (Formatting is a little messed up when I pasted it in)

```
public class Stats {

  public static void main(String[] argv) {
     int[][] data = { 
     { 0, 2, 4, 5, 5, 8 },
     { 1, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9 },
     { -4, -2, -2, 3, 12, 12, 42 },
     { 0 },
     { 1, 2 },
     { 1, 1 },
     { 1, 2, 3 },
     { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 },
     { -2, -2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 },
     { -7, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4 },
    };
  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     Results results = stats(data[i]);
     printResults(results);
  }
}

 private static void printArray(int[] x, boolean nl) {
  System.out.print("[");
  for (int i = 0, j = x.length - 1; i < j; i++)
     System.out.print(x[i] + ",");
  System.out.print(x[x.length - 1] + "]");
  if (nl) System.out.println();
}

private static void printResults(Results r) {
  printArray(r.data, true);
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("...mean: ");
  sb.append(r.mean).append("; median: "). append(r.median).
     append("; mode: "). append(r.nomode ? "modeless" : r.mode).
     append("; cardinality: ").append(r.cardinality).
     append("; range: ").append(r.range);
  System.out.println(sb);
  System.out.println();
}

static class Results {
  public int[] data; 
  public int cardinality;
  public int range;
  public double mean;
  public double median;
  public int mode;
  public boolean nomode;
}

private static Results stats(int[] data) {
   int      sum = 0,
            range,
            count = 0,
            max = data[0],
            min = data[0],
            mode,
            middle = data.length / 2,
            cardinality = data.length;
   double   mean = 0,
            median;
   Stats Results = new Stats();

   for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       sum += data[i];
       if (data[i] < min){
           min = data[i];
       }
       if (data[i] > max){
           max = data[i];
       }
       if (data[i] > count){
           count = data[i];
           mode = i;
       }
   }
   if (data.length % 2 == 1){
       median = data.length / 2;
   } else {
       median = data[middle - 1] + data[middle] / 2;
   }
   mean = sum / data.length;
   range = max - min;



 }
```

}

Comment: you are creating an instance of Stats, but your signature says you need an instance of Results. Since you don't show your Results class, all we can say is: instantiate that class and set the values, then return it

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: we dont know the fields of calss `Stats`

Comment: You have an instance called `Results` but you are supposed to return a type `Results`. That doesn't seem possible. You should show the error you are receiving, as this will clarify the situation.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod seeing as he has to return an instance of 'Results', that doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: @Stultuske right, i saw it. this should give compile error  `Stats Results = new Stats() `

Comment: Why should that give a compile error? that should compile just fine, as long as he also has a Stats class with a default compiler

Comment: I need to instantiate and return a Results object that contains the calculations for the int[] parameter.  The calculations are:  range, mean, median, mode.

Answer (score 0):

Method declaration should be like below:

```
private static Results stats(int[] data){
    ....
    .....
    return Results;
}
```

Return type should be class name not object name which is Stats
and add return statement as above before method ends.

Comment: you are assuming he doesn't have a class called Results. This should be a comment, rather than an answer.